# Where are debug symbols for backported packages?

Tags: debug, backport

Where can I download Linux kernel 2.6.35-25 debug symbols for kernel that comes from lucid-backports repository (I have enabled lucid-backports repository on Ubuntu 10.04 in /etc/apt/sources.list)?

The problem with debug symbols [located here](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) is that debug symbols for 2.6.35-25 linux kernel server image does not match with the binary I get from lucid back-ports repository:

> ii  linux-image-2.6.35-25-server
> 2.6.35-25.44~lucid1                    Linux kernel image for version 2.6.35
> on x86 ii
> linux-image-2.6.35-25-server-dbgsym
> 2.6.35-25.44                           Linux kernel debug image for version
> 2.6.35

And hence the system-tap (stap) fails:

> root@www:~/stap#  stap para-callgraph-verbose.stp 'kernel.function("*@fs/proc*.c")' 'kernel.function("vfs_read")' -c "cat /proc/sys/vm/*"
>
> ERROR: Build-id
> mismatch: "kernel" vs.
> "vmlinux-2.6.35-25-server"

There are also some reasons why I would prefer not to build linux kernel myself just to get stap working.

Answer (score 1):

You should post your repository list so we can see how you've added it. I would firstly report the problem to the kernel backports people, they're the only people who can sort the issue out permanently or explain why they won't.

See: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs

Secondly, you could do an easier compile of the kernel by using the source package to generate a deb with symbols:

```
apt-get source linux-kernel
etc
```

Answer (score 0):

The [page](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux/) on ddebs.ubuntu.com that you linked to only contains the ddebs for packages built from the `linux` source package. However, the backported kernels are not built from that source package; they instead come from the `linux-lts-backport-maverick` source package:

```
(lucid-amd64)evan@caron:~$ apt-cache show linux-image-2.6.35-25-server | grep '^Source'
Source: linux-lts-backport-maverick
```

By contrast, here is the same query on the kernel released with Ubuntu 10.04 (which was 2.6.32):

```
(lucid-amd64)evan@caron:~$ apt-cache show linux-image-2.6.32-21-server | grep '^Source'
Source: linux
```

If you instead look at the [ddebs page for the `linux-lts-backport-maverick` source package](http://ddebs.ubuntu.com/pool/main/l/linux-lts-backport-maverick/), you'll find ddebs for the kernel you're using.

As a side note, in spite of their name, the LTS backport kernels are released to the Updates pocket (e.g. `lucid-updates`), not to the Backports pocket (`lucid-backports`), as they are not backported through the [Ubuntu Backports project](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuBackports). Due to their limited level of support, packages which are backported as true backports do not have debug symbols available on ddebs.ubuntu.com in order to save space.